# Add additional row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have following data (view):

```
 Declare @YourTable table ([Event] varchar(100),[Start] DateTime,[End] DateTime, [Tag] varchar(25))
  Insert Into @YourTable values
  ('10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B','9/9/16 10:44:05.000','9/9/16 10:48:08.000','Big'),
  ('10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B','9/9/16 10:44:10.000','9/9/16 10:49:40.000','Big'),
  ('10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B','9/9/16 10:50:03.000','9/9/16 10:51:04.000','Small'),
  ('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 12:51:07.000','4/4/16 13:58:09.000','Big'),
  ('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 14:04:04.000','4/4/16 14:29:00.000','Small'),
  ('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 14:51:02.000','4/4/16 14:58:00.000','Big'),
  ('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 15:04:06.000','4/4/16 15:29:08.000','Small'),
  ('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4-4-16 15:45:08.000','4-4-16 15:55:09.000','Big'),
  ('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4-4-16 16:22:08.000','4-4-16 16:40:09.000','Big'),
  ('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 16:50:04.000','4/4/16 16:55:00.000','Small'),
  ('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 17:05:02.000','4/4/16 17:20:00.000','Big'),
  ('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 17:22:06.000','4/4/16 17:29:08.000','Small'),
  ('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002W 11-PSV-401002D','4/4/16 16:04:01.000','4/4/16 16:45:00.000','Big');
```

I use following query to get result I need, group by event and order by start, and change big to small whenever small goes after big:

```
 Select [Event]
  ,[Start]
  ,[End] 
  ,[Tag]
  ,[Tag_new] = case when Tag='Big' and 'Small' = Lead(Tag,1,Tag) over (Partition By Event Order By Start) then 'Small' else tag end
  From  @YourTable

                                       Event    Start                   End                     Tag  Tag_new
10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B    2016-09-09 10:44:05.000 2016-09-09 10:48:08.000 Big   Big
10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B    2016-09-09 10:44:10.000 2016-09-09 10:49:40.000 Big   Small
10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B    2016-09-09 10:50:03.000 2016-09-09 10:51:04.000 Small Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 12:51:07.000 2016-04-04 13:58:09.000 Big   Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 14:04:04.000 2016-04-04 14:29:00.000 Small Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 14:51:02.000 2016-04-04 14:58:00.000 Big   Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 15:04:06.000 2016-04-04 15:29:08.000 Small Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 15:45:08.000 2016-04-04 15:55:09.000 Big   Big
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 16:22:08.000 2016-04-04 16:40:09.000 Big   Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 16:50:04.000 2016-04-04 16:55:00.000 Small Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 17:05:02.000 2016-04-04 17:20:00.000 Big   Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 17:22:06.000 2016-04-04 17:29:08.000 Small Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002W 11-PSV-401002D     2016-04-04 16:04:01.000 2016-04-04 16:45:00.000 Big   Big
```

I need to apply one more exception, whenever sequence below appears in Tag column in a group, it should add aditional row after small and before big with starttime, endtime and Tag_new accordingly, and starttime should be 1 sec late than previous date endtime and endtime is 1 sec late than starttime and Tag_new is "Bad":

```
Small
Big
Small
```

I'd like to get something like below:

```
                                       Event    Start                   End                     Tag  Tag_new
10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B    2016-09-09 10:44:05.000 2016-09-09 10:48:08.000 Big   Big
10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B    2016-09-09 10:44:10.000 2016-09-09 10:49:40.000 Big   Small
10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B    2016-09-09 10:50:03.000 2016-09-09 10:51:04.000 Small Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 12:51:07.000 2016-04-04 13:58:09.000 Big   Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 14:04:04.000 2016-04-04 14:29:00.000 Small Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 14:29:01.000 2016-04-04 14:29:02.000 Bad   Bad
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 14:51:02.000 2016-04-04 14:58:00.000 Big   Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 15:04:06.000 2016-04-04 15:29:08.000 Small Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 15:45:08.000 2016-04-04 15:55:09.000 Big   Big
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 16:22:08.000 2016-04-04 16:40:09.000 Big   Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 16:50:04.000 2016-04-04 16:55:00.000 Small Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 16:55:01.000 2016-04-04 16:55:02.000 Bad   Bad
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 17:05:02.000 2016-04-04 17:20:00.000 Big   Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B     2016-04-04 17:22:06.000 2016-04-04 17:29:08.000 Small Small
11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002W 11-PSV-401002D     2016-04-04 16:04:01.000 2016-04-04 16:45:00.000 Big   Big
```

Comment: I voted this up, because the question is quite okay. There is sample code to copy'n'paste, own effort and a quite clear explanation. The whole approach smells a bit and is - uhm - complicated... SQL Server might not be the best tool for this. But the question itself does neither deserve the `Close because unclear´ nor does it deserve a down-vote. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: thanks Shnugo for voted it up

Comment: Why have you reposted this question, which was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026002/group-and-order-with-additional-exception/40027420#40027420 ?

Comment: sorry iamdave, after few testing today I figured out that the changing small to small2 is not what I need since if there is small-big-small-big-small-big-small it gives small2 for two group and this was wrong direction, the right one is to add row after small and before big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This design smells, but you might try something like this:

**You should avoid culture specific datetime literals!**

```
Declare @YourTable table ([Event] varchar(100),[Start] DateTime,[End] DateTime, [Tag] varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B','9/9/16 10:44:05.000','9/9/16 10:48:08.000','Big'),
('10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B','9/9/16 10:44:10.000','9/9/16 10:49:40.000','Big'),
('10PIC700422.PV 10-PSV-700073A 10-PSV-700073B','9/9/16 10:50:03.000','9/9/16 10:51:04.000','Small'),
('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 12:51:07.000','4/4/16 13:58:09.000','Big'),
('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 14:04:04.000','4/4/16 14:29:00.000','Small'),
('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 14:51:02.000','4/4/16 14:58:00.000','Big'),
('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 15:04:06.000','4/4/16 15:29:08.000','Small'),
('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4-4-16 15:45:08.000','4-4-16 15:55:09.000','Big'),
('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4-4-16 16:22:08.000','4-4-16 16:40:09.000','Big'),
('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 16:50:04.000','4/4/16 16:55:00.000','Small'),
('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 17:05:02.000','4/4/16 17:20:00.000','Big'),
('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002A 11-PSV-401002B','4/4/16 17:22:06.000','4/4/16 17:29:08.000','Small'),
('11PIC41010.PV 11-PSV-401002W 11-PSV-401002D','4/4/16 16:04:01.000','4/4/16 16:45:00.000','Big');
```

--Add a running row-number to your query and a `0` for all `original` rows

```
WITH YourQueryEnhanced AS
(
    Select [Event]
    ,[Start]
    ,[End] 
    ,[Tag]
    ,[Tag_new] = case when Tag='Big' and 'Small' = Lead(Tag,1,Tag) over (Partition By [Event] Order By Start) then 'Small' else tag end
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS SortInx --You should put a secure ORDER BY here!!!
    ,0 AS InnerSortInx
    From  @YourTable
)
```

--Use `LAG()` to detect your sequence. There is one problem with overlapping bad sequences!

```
,BadMarked AS
(
    SELECT *
        ,CASE WHEN LAG([Tag],1) OVER(Order By SortInx)='Small' 
                AND LAG([Tag],2) OVER(Order By SortInx)='Big' 
                AND LAG([Tag],3) OVER(Order By SortInx)='Small' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BadSequence 

    FROM YourQueryEnhanced
)
```

--This will select all `original` rows and will add a `bad` row for each row marked as `BadSequence`. The SortInx is set to the prev value, the inner sortInx is set to `1`, hence the `ORDER BY` will push the `bad` rows in the proper place

```
    SELECT *
    FROM BadMarked

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT [Event],[Start],[End],'Bad','Bad',SortInx-1,1,2 
    FROM BadMarked 
    WHERE BadMarked.BadSequence=1
    ORDER BY SortInx,InnerSortInx
```

**Attention**

This will add one more bad row to your result, as you stated this in your expected result.

The reason are your lines 3 to 7 where you have small-big-small-big-small. The middle `small` belongs to both sequences.

You must either solve this with more logic in the place (more calls to `LAG()` to look further back), where the bad sequence is detected, or you wrap the last select as one more `CTE` and use `LAG()` again to remove bad rows you don't want.

Comment: Shnugo, thanks for code but this seems to be not I need.

Comment: @JoeGreen, please elaborate... Why not?

Comment: ok, I'll try to handle additional row(still not sure how to do it), what about adding 1 second to starttime and endtime?

Comment: @JoeGreen try dateadd()

Answer (score 1):

@Shnugo: you were really close. Thanks for solution!!!

```
WITH YourQueryEnhanced AS
(
Select [Event]
,[Start]
,[End] 
,[Tag]
,[Tag_new] = case when Tag='Big' and 'Small' = Lead(Tag,1,Tag) over (Partition By [Event] Order By Start) then 'Small' else tag end
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By [Event] Order By Start) AS SortInx --You     should put a secure ORDER BY here!!!
,0 AS InnerSortInx
From  @YourTable
), BadMarked AS
(
 SELECT *
    ,CASE WHEN LAG([Tag],1) OVER(Order By SortInx)='Small' 
            AND LAG([Tag],2) OVER(Order By SortInx)='Big' 
            AND LAG([Tag],3) OVER(Order By SortInx)='Big' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END     AS BadSequence 
FROM YourQueryEnhanced 
) 
select * from
(
SELECT *
FROM BadMarked
UNION ALL 
    SELECT [Event],DATEADD(s, -1, [Start]) [Start],    [End],'Bad','Bad',SortInx-1,1,2 
FROM BadMarked 
WHERE BadMarked.BadSequence=1
) a order by [Event]
,[Start]
```